# Piping Before and After switch in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I created a system restore point. I want to restore it. The restore point description is 'rajiv' and the sequence number is 1.

```
get-computerrestorepoint | where description -eq 'rajiv' | Select-Object -ExpandPropert
y SequenceNumber | Restore-Computer -RestorePoint
```

I can also get it working by:

```
Restore-Computer -RestorePoint (get-computerrestorepoint | where description -eq 'rajiv' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SequenceNumber)
```

For another approach, In powershell we can use the before and after switch to grab the output of the previous or next pipeline. How to do this? Please help and guide with some documentation.

Comment: i have no idea what you mean by `before and after switch` [*blush*] ... would you please point me to the documents on that?

Comment: taking the output from the previous pipeline and using it in the current operation, same can be done for after. I read it somewhere in the documentation, but forgot the location :(

Comment: the only things i can think of are `-PipelineVarible` and - possibly - the `begin{}`, process{}, and `end{}` blocks. other than that, i am unable to guess what you are talking about. [*blush*]

Comment: [You cannot pipe input to the `Restore-Computer` cmdlet.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/restore-computer?view=powershell-4.0) Hence, the firstly mentioned example must fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

restore-computer doesn't take pipeline input, so you have to use foreach-object, as I replied on technet.